# Submitting the form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

When I click the search icon, it alerts `ok`, but not `h`.

[image: See the display]

According to my codes below, it should alert both `ok` & `h`.

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])){ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('h');</script>"; 
} ?>
<form method="post">
  <div class="col_1">
    <select name="search_type" required="">
      <option value="0">Anywhere</option>
      <option value="1">Start With</option>
      <option value="2">End With</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col_2">
    <input type="number" name="search_q" data-type="num" maxlength="10" placeholder="Digit" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="col_3">
    <input type="submit" name="search" id="input_submit" hidden />
    <button type="submit" id="button_submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
  $('#input_submit').click();
  alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending a `search` value in the request.

The `<input name="search" />` is hidden (so not being clicked) and even if it was visible it has no `value` to send in the request.

To fix this remove that `input` and put the `name` and `value` attributes on the `<button>` instead:

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['search']))
{ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('h');</script>"; 
} ?>

<form method="post">
  <div class="col_1">
    <select name="search_type" required="">
      <option value="0">Anywhere</option>
      <option value="1">Start With</option>
      <option value="2">End With</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col_2">
    <input type="number" name="search_q" data-type="num" maxlength="10" placeholder="Digit" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="col_3">
    <button type="submit" id="button_submit" name="search" value="foobar">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
  $('#input_submit').click();
  console.log("ok");
});
```